# How to locate div positon according to the frame size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In normal window, `<div>` are arranged horizontally. Once the window size becomes smaller, `<div>` are stacked vertically. They are shown in the attached images.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

For that I made Blocks and boxes. Boxes are inside the Block.

```css
.blocks {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 85%;
  min-height: 420px;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.blocks .box1 img,
.blocks .box2 img,
.blocks .box3 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box1 p_1" style="background-color: #ccffe5;">
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box2 p_1" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box3 p_1" style="background-color: #ccffe5;">
    <h1>BOX 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

With that arrangement, they are always arranged horizontally.

How can I arrange them horizontally and vertically according to the window size?

EDIT:

[image: imge]

Comment: Do you mean rearrange the boxes in other order

Comment: @PeterWilson,yes. 
 
Please see here in the preview. wordpress.org/themes/skt-spa . The size is dynamically changed from small to big once the frame getting smaller than a limit. Then positioned itself at the centre horizontally of the page. How it can be done? Our approach has sticking to left problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is depend on many things as this design is **responsive**

**1. Container width**

-- on large screens `lg >= 1200px` the container width is `1170px`
-- on medium screens `md >= 992px` the container width is `970px`
-- on small screens `sm >= 786px` the container width is `750px`
-- on extra small screens `xs < 768px` the container width is `auto`

**2. column width**

Column width is calculated upon container width (12 column per container row)
which mean the colum width will get changed on each screen size

on extra small screens the container  is auto width which mean it will be 100% of the device width so if you need to control the widths on extra small screens you have to do it manually

you can use `max-width` or if you want not use bootstrap grid in this section and building your own like

```
.blocks{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
 },
 [class*='box']{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
```

**or**

```
 .blocks{
    width:100%;
 },
 .blocks:after{
    display:table;
    content:"";
    clear:both;
 }
 [class*='box']{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
```

**EDIT**

if you plan to have equal heights of all boxes you have to know what is the changeable height component in each box which is from what I can see is the text.

you could do handle this by fixing its height:

```css
.blocks{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
 }
[class*='box']{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
  vertical-align:top;
  height: 520px;
}
[class*='box'] p{
    height: 100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="box1 " style="background-color: #ccffe5;">
    <img src='https://placehold.it/200x300'/>
    <h1>BOX 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box2 " style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
    <img src='https://placehold.it/200x300'/>
    <h1>BOX 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box3 " style="background-color: #ccffe5;">
    <img src='https://placehold.it/200x300'/>
    <h1>BOX 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  Lorem Ipsum hustry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though it is still not arranged vertically, I like the first option for horizontally arrangement. It looks good for small window or big window. This is the best option for horizontal arrangement so far for me. Just one thing, the bottom are not in same height, how can I change CSS to have equal height for all boxes? I have added image as EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

It will correct float when you add "width" and "float":

```
.box1, .box2, .box3 {   
    width: 200px;
    float:left;     
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;

    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You will need a fixed width of the boxes (or at least a min-width)

Comment: Please see here in the preview. https://wordpress.org/themes/skt-spa/ . The size is dynamically changed from small to big once the frame getting smaller than a limit. Then positioned itself at the centre horizontally of the page. How it can be done? Our approach has sticking to left problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let the CSS grid take care of the layout. 
Add a div with a class "row" within your "blocks" div.

Remove the "width" and "display: inline-block" property from your box elements.

Please RTFM: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

There is no need to give an index to the box classes if they are all similar. Just use "box".

Comment: Please see here in the preview. https://wordpress.org/themes/skt-spa/ . The size is dynamically changed from small to big once the frame getting smaller than a limit. Then positioned itself at the centre horizontally of the page. How it can be done?